# Passing down use state values gives undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have child Component with input, and in the parent I've a button that disabled based on this input.

I thought about creating 'top level' state and pass the values like this:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [projectName, setProjectName] = useState('')


  return (
    <>
    <Child projectName={projectName} setProjectName={setProjectName} />
    <button disabled={projectName.length === 6}/>
    </>
  )
}
```

My question is, Is it solid react way to implement this?

In the child component I'm getting undefined for both  `projectName` and `setProjectName`, why is it happening and how can I solve this?

Child Component:

```
const Child= ({projectName, setProjectName}) => {

    return (
        <>
            <h2><StyledInlineSpan>Projects / </StyledInlineSpan>Create New Project</h2>
            <Input autoFocus placeholder="Project Name" value={projectName} onChange={({ target }) => { setProjectName(target.value) }}  />
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is solid. Can you please post the code of `Child` component as well

Comment: @SinanYaman I edited the question with the child cmp

Comment: @ScrapeW  can you please also show your import statements in both components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't get an `undefined`, I think it is a problem with your `Input` component. I created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-breeze-myj6n?file=/src/Child.js) with the same use case. As you type into the input, the `Child` component will change the state variable and the parent uses it.

It is completely fine to create a controlled Child component like this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have mis-spelled `Input`.

In React if the first letter of any HTML tag is capital, then it is treated as a custom React component.

Simply rename this

```
 <Input autoFocus placeholder="Project Name" value={projectName} onChange={({ target }) => { setProjectName(target.value) }}  />
```

to

```
<input autoFocus placeholder="Project Name" value={projectName} onChange={({ target }) => { setProjectName(target.value) }}  />
```

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather above state is right. You can cross check.

Comment: Sure, My Bad. I thought you have written, "Custom React Hook". Ya, I take my comment back. Sorry

Comment: You are awesome :) :) :) :) CHEERS !!! 
God bless you